# YII 2: Integrate Gridview Module on a page

Tags: php, gridview, datagridview, yii2

I'm very much new to YII 2. I have a requirement where I need to [integrate this](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/extendedGridView#gridcolumns) to the page as a Grid view.

Flow the Grid page will be:

1) User Logins to the website via Login Form.
2) Once the authentication of success, I'm redirecting it to My Orders Grid View Page.

The following is the code that I have used to redirect to the page.

*SiteController.php*

```
public function actionLogin()
{       
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    $modelUser = new UserLogin();

    if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
        $temp = $modelUser::find()->where(['user_login_username' => $_POST['LoginForm']['username'], 'user_login_password' => md5($_POST['LoginForm']['password'])])->one();
        $session->set('user_id', $temp['user_login_id']);
        $session->set('user_name', $temp['user_login_username']);
        if (empty($temp)) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('loginFailure', "Authentication Failed. Please try Again..!");
            return $this->redirect(\Yii::$app->request->getReferrer());
        } else {                
            return $this->render('orders', ['model' => $modelUser,]);
        }
    }
    return $this->render('login', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

I have created the `orders.php` for a view which contain only header and footer in it.

*orders.php*

```
public function actionOrders() {
    $modelUser = new UserLogin();
    $query = UserLogin::findAll();
    $count = $query->count();
    $pagination = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $count]);
    $articles = $query->offset($pagination->offset)
                ->limit($pagination->limit)
                ->all();
    echo LinkPager::widget([
            'pagination' => $pagination,
        ]);
}
```

Can any one can guide me in doing it in step by step, please?

Comment: see here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#gridview

Comment: what you are trying is yii gridview which is still not updated for yii2. better use gridview.

Comment: Show the code for your arction in orders controller and the related view please

Comment: @scaisEdge, the following is the code that in ActionOrders

public function actionOrders() {
  $modelUser = new UserLogin();
  $query = UserLogin::findAll();
  $count = $query->count();
  $pagination = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $count]);
  $articles = $query->offset($pagination->offset)
     ->limit($pagination->limit)
     ->all();
  echo LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $pagination,
   ]);
 }

Comment: @Kiran Kumar please edit your question and add the code poperly formatted.  In which controller is placed?